# Convrt ERB data-attribuites to SLIM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, slim-lang

I have the problem with insert ruby code in html data-attribuites with SLIM, in erb template

```
<li data-notifications='<%= render template: "notifications/index", formats: [:json] %>'>
```

erb2slim convertor suggest this

```
i[data-notifications="<ruby code=\"= render template: &quot;notifications/index&quot;, formats: [:json]\"></ruby>"]
```

But it's raise slim parser error: Expected attribute

Comment: The answer looks correct at first glance--and so does the comment, this seems like an unusual approach.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this: https://github.com/slim-template/slim#ruby-attributes

```
i[data-notifications="<ruby code=\"= render template: &quot;notifications/index&quot;, formats: [:json]\"></ruby>"]
```

should be something more like

```
i[data-notifications=(render template: "notifications/index", formats: [:json])]
```

(I'm curious as to why you're rendering a template there, but this should be closer, syntax-wise.)

Comment: Thank you, but in this case it render data-notifications=[]

Comment: I try to create notification system with this solution
https://gorails.com/episodes/sharing-data-with-javascript

Comment: Hmm, and there are Notification records in the database, with read_at:nil and where the recipient is your user? Looking at that GoRails code, that notifications/index template just renders an array of them, retrieved like so: `@notifications = Notification.where(recipient: current_user).unread`